# Keeping unique rows based on information from 2 of three columns

Tags: awk, uniq

Suppose you have a file like this:

```
NW_006521251.1  428 84134
NW_006521251.1  511 84135
NW_006521038.1  202 84155
NW_006521038.1  1743 84153
NW_006521038.1  1743 84154
NW_006520495.1  198 84159
NW_006520086.1  473 84178
NW_006520086.1  511 84180
```

I want to keep the unique rows based on columns 1 and 2 (i.e. not just column two as this number may repeat under a different label in column one).

Such that I get this as output (removes the second repeat of `NW_006521038.1  1743` from the list):

```
    NW_006521251.1  428 84134
    NW_006521251.1  511 84135
    NW_006521038.1  202 84155
    NW_006521038.1  1743 84153
    NW_006520495.1  198 84159
    NW_006520086.1  473 84178
    NW_006520086.1  511 84180
```

Is there a way to do this with awk?
Using `uniq file` doesn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a "famous" awk idiom for exactly this. You want to do:

```
awk '!seen[$1,$2]++' file
```

That creates an associative array "seen" with the 2 columns as the key. Use the post-increment operator so that, for the first time you encounter that key, the value is zero. The use the negation operator for a "true" result the first time you see the key.

Comment: I can't believe how short this awk script is. That's an impressive use of the conditional expression.

Comment: @glenn-jackman Just curious if we need to ignore case-sensitive lines and keep whichever comes first. What should we include in it? IGNORECASE=1 doesn't seem to be working with this. TIA.

Comment: Use `tolower()` or `toupper()`

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind that the output is sorted:

```
sort -u -k1,2 file
```

- `-u` - unique
- `-k1,2` - use fields 1 and 2 together as the key