# Don't print the same string again if it was found between two files

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, python

I'm looking for the string `SUCCESS` into the `file_1` &  `file_2` which in this case looks for the string and prints it based on whether its there on only `file_1` or on both `file_1` and `file_2` while I'm looking it to print only once either its on both the file of one. How that can be done?

```
$ grep SUCCESS file_1  file_2
```

### Result:

```
file_1:Host fox_01 is SUCCESS
file_2:Host fox_02 is SUCCESS
file_2:Host fox_01 is SUCCESS
```

I'm open to any advice or solution, not necessarily grep.

Comment: So you just want to know if the string `SUCCESS` is in either file? Your question is a bit hard to understand, it would help if you gave an example of your desired output.

Comment: @rustyshackleford, sorry for not making it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk '/SUCCESS/ && !a[$0]++' file_1 file_2

Host fox_01 is SUCCESS
Host fox_02 is SUCCESS
```

will check for the keyword "SUCCESS" and ignores duplicate

Comment: Excellent @msp9011, I [referred the link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439539/keeping-unique-rows-based-on-information-from-2-of-three-columns)

Comment: Is there a better way rather using `&&` operator.

Comment: @krock1516 may I know whats the difficulty in using `&&`

Comment: -@msp9011, I see no difficulty but wondering if there can be a better way? Isn't that good question :-) .

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -h` to not print the file names, and then `awk` [to suppress duplicate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix):

```
grep -h SUCCESS file_1  file_2 | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

or if you wish to sort:

```
grep -h SUCCESS file_1  file_2 | sort -u
```

Comment: Excellent @Rovo, I came around the same awk idiom.

Comment: I [referred the link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439539/keeping-unique-rows-based-on-information-from-2-of-three-columns)