# How to remove lines with identical content in the same column with awk

Tags: awk

I've got massive file looking similar to that:

```
H2,3,5,9,ef,ty,i;
H2,7,5,6,rt,hg,j;
T2,5,5,0,207,3.7,00,...,2023:46:18:14:31,76;
T2,5,5,0,207,3.5,00,...,2023:46:18:14:31,76;
T2,5,5,0,119,3.5,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,10;
T2,5,5,0,207,3.5,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,15;
T2,5,5,0,186,3.4,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,16;
T2,5,5,0,207,4.6,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,30;
....
```

I need to get rid of lines:

1. Starting from T2,5,5,0,207
2. Having the repeating time mark in field 15

and leave all other lines untouched.

I tried that in different combinations but none of what I checked worked so far:

```
awk -F ',' ' x!=$15 { if ($1 == T2 && $5 == 207) {x=$15; print$0} else print$0} ' test > test1
```

I would really appreciate any advice!!
Thanks

Comment: There's a few different things you might mean by that description. Make sure to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrate your needs.

Comment: If the lines you want to remove are sequential and the entire line is duplicate, you might want to use `uniq` instead.

Comment: Should the removed records have `T2,5,5,0,207` _specifically_ as their first fields, or should any record with non-unique five first fields be deleted?  Is the second condition dependent or independent of the first condition? I.e., should all records with duplicated timestamps be deleted, or only those that _also_ has duplicated five first fields?

Comment: Was `2023:46:18:14:31` or `76;` the "_repeating time mark in field 15_"? You omitted a whole load of fields so it was impossible to count. (You could have referenced _field 9_ or maybe _field 10_ so that the description matched the data.) Next time you have a question please try to ensure you have example data that can be used for testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Try this:

```
$ awk -F, '!seen[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$8]++' file
```

##### Output

```
H2,3,5,9,ef,ty,i;
H2,7,5,6,rt,hg,j;
T2,5,5,0,207,3.7,00,...,2023:46:18:14:31,76;
T2,5,5,0,119,3.5,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,10;
T2,5,5,0,186,3.4,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,16;
```

##### Explanations

- the default behavior of `awk` on a true condition is to `print`, that's why it's not needed here
- the `!seen[x]++` is a shorthand to do `uniq` operation. Check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439540/12574)

##### Portability

Works with:

- `gawk`
- `mawk`
- `busybox awk`
- `nawk` (default `freeBSD` `awk`)

And all `awk` implementations, thanks [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735992/how-to-remove-lines-with-identical-content-in-the-same-column-with-awk/735995?noredirect=1#comment1397461_735995)

Original snippet for the records:

```
awk -F, '
     ($1=="T2" && $2==5 && $3==5 && $4==0 && $5==207 && !seen[$8]++) ||
    !($1=="T2" && $2==5 && $3==5 && $4==0 && $5==207)
' file
```

Comment: It worked, excellent! Did not manage to decrypt the code yet but I will for sure. Many thanks

Comment: Isn't the concatenation of field values into a single key potentially ambiguous? Compare `printf '%s\n' 1,2,34,5 1,23,4,5 | awk -F, '!seen[$1$2$3$4]++'` and `printf '%s\n' 1,2,34,5 1,23,4,5 | awk -F, '!seen[$1,$2,$3,$4]++'` for example

Comment: also it's mentioned lines starting with `T2,5,5,0,207,` (representing fields #1~#5) not all the others lines which you wrongly did like that.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, added `,` between fields. I added `$8` to remove duplicate dates.

Comment: @GillesQuénot TBH I'm not sure how portable the `a[$1,$2,$3,$4]` syntax is - it's supported explicitly in GAWK (providing pseudo multidimensional array capability) and seems to work in MAWK though

Comment: Added Portability section

Comment: @steeldriver that pseudo-multi-dimensional array syntax `a[$1,$2,$3,$4]` is portable to all awks, it's the alternative arrays of arrays syntax `a[$1][$2][$3][$4]` that's non-portable and requires GNU awk (and possibly some other modern awks that share gawk's code and features now, e.g. mawk 2, but it's not part of POSIX).

Comment: @EdMorton thanks that's good to know

Comment: $ awk -F, '!seen[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$8]++' did not work correctly since file is more complicated than I posted earlier and quite a few lines satisfy to mentioned conditiones so I have to make sure that at least $1 and $5 matches to initial strings "T2" and 207 accordingly.

Comment: Feel free to adapt it

Answer (score 1):

Does this what you want?

```
$ awk -F, '/^T2,5,5,0,207,/ && seen[$15]++{ next }1' infile
H2,3,5,9,ef,ty,i;
H2,7,5,6,rt,hg,j;
T2,5,5,0,207,3.7,00,...,2023:46:18:14:31,76;
T2,5,5,0,119,3.5,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,10;
T2,5,5,0,207,3.5,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,15;
T2,5,5,0,186,3.4,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,16;
....
```

print first line have seen with `T2,5,5,0,207` matching at first five fields and with whatever timestamp in its field #15 then skip other similar lines with the same five starting fields and same timestamp as previously seen; it will also print all other lines unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I need to get rid of duplicates by fields:

```bash
awk -F, '!(/^T2,5,5,0,207/ && A[$(NF-1)]++)' file
H2,3,5,9,ef,ty,i;
H2,7,5,6,rt,hg,j;
T2,5,5,0,207,3.7,00,...,2023:46:18:14:31,76;
T2,5,5,0,119,3.5,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,10;
T2,5,5,0,207,3.5,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,15;
T2,5,5,0,186,3.4,00,...,2023:46:18:14:32,16;
```

`A[$(NF-1)]` - in this file `A[$9]`